# stop to go on onPostExecute() if parsing exception onpreexecute() occurs

Tags: android

am using asynchronous task for hitting the web service url and retrieve the result from server but some time in onPreExecute() method if parsing exception occurs i handle it on catch() method,now i want to Halt the processing next means execution not go to OnpostExecute() method ,so how to stop execution process for going it to OnPostExecute()
my code are below

```
    @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
             dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainMenu.this);
             dialog.setMessage("Processing...");
             dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
             dialog.setCancelable(false);
             dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

            if (dialog.isShowing())
            {
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
             Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this, filterpagetabs.class);
                 startActivity(i);



    }
        @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try{    
            try {
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                        "http://www.mobi/iphonejh/output.php?estado=1");
                MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);



            }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a parsingSuccessful boolean variable at the top with value true. In the catch of the parse exception set in on false. In the postExecute, use an if statement to check if the parsing has been successfully done and put the onPostExecute lines in this if statement.

Like this:

```
private boolean parsingSuccessful = true;

@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainMenu.this);
         dialog.setMessage("Processing...");
         dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
         dialog.setCancelable(false);
         dialog.show();
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (parsingSuccessful == true){
            if (dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this, filterpagetabs.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }
}
    @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) { 
        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                    "http://www.mobi/iphonejh/output.php?estado=1");
            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            parsingSuccessful = false;
```

}

Comment: well it works ... but ... you can do this without parsingSuccessful var ... doInBackground returns Boolean which will be passed to onPostExecute(...) as `final Boolean success` ...

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

"A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)"

Although, since the bulk of your work is already done i.e. network I/O, it may be better just to return a success boolean and check that `onPostExecute`